# Use filter on an array for a specific index?

Tags: javascript

Basic question but its something that I've never quite understood with these array methods.

Say I have an array such as:

```
[[ 'PENNY', 0 ],[ 'NICKEL', 0 ],[ 'DIME', 20 ],[ 'QUARTER', 50 ]]
```

and I wanted to use filter to return a new array in which only elements are returned whose first index is greater than 0.

So it would return an array like so:

```
[ [ 'DIME', 20 ],[ 'QUARTER', 50 ]].
```

How would I go about this using filter? Some clarification would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `filter` as you mention in question for compare if value is `>` of 0 like:

```js
const array =  [[ 'PENNY', 0 ],[ 'NICKEL', 0 ],[ 'DIME', 20 ],[ 'QUARTER', 50 ]];
console.log(array.filter(el => el[1] > 0));
```

Reference:

- [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Yeah... That's kinda embarrassing. No idea why it didn't work for me when I tried - probably console logged the wrong value. Thank you anyway for the clarification!

Answer (score 3):

Filter by the second element:

```js
const array = [[ 'PENNY', 0 ],[ 'NICKEL', 0 ],[ 'DIME', 20 ],[ 'QUARTER', 50 ]];

const filtered = array.filter(([, count]) => count > 0);

console.log(filtered);
```

`[, count]` is destructuring, which you can read about in full [here](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/)

Comment: Nice tip, i didn't know :)

Answer (score 0):

```
const array = [[ 'PENNY', 0 ],[ 'NICKEL', 0 ],[ 'DIME', 20 ],[ 'QUARTER', 50 ]]
 
const arrayFiltered = array.filter((item) => item[1] > 0)
console.log(arrayFiltered)
```

filter() method return a new array based on the rule you specify inside.
In this case, we want a new array with item[1] (the index of our array) to be > 0.

Comment: Same as the top voted answer